# Display Near Match Text in CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I like to get a list of full-text fuzzy matching terms.  For ex.

```
SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONTAINS(COL1,'RUMP')
```

I like to get a list of what was matched, 'Trump','Trumps','crump', and not the entire column.

Comment: You can achieve this using wildcard. In your case, `SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE CONTAINS(COL1,'%RUMP%')` should work

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is not clear what you want as output. Are you saying you are wanting the query to only return a portion of the data found in your column? Meaning if the column contained something like "I like playing trump cards" you would want it to only return "trump". I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Hi, you are the first reply to my first post.  Yes, I like to get only the "trump."  The web developers asked if they can get only the matching list to highlight in the return result set.  "I like playing <highlight>Trump</highlight> cards"